# Converting JSON object format using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs.I want to change the format of the JSON object code which I am getting into some new format.Below is the format.

```
$scope.filters={"filters":
                         [{"filterId":"106","filtername":"Service Line","filterValue":"ADI"},
                          {"filterId":"107","filtername":"Service Line","filterValue":"L"},
                          {"filterId":"108","filtername":"Service Line","filterValue":"M"},
                          {"filterId":"109","filtername":"Location","filterValue":"N"},
                          {"filterId":"110","filtername":"Band","filterValue":"O"}

                          ]};
```

I want this to be changed into below format using angularjs.

```
$scope.filters=[{"filters":
                                {"ServiceLine":["ADI","L","M"],
                                    "Location":["N"],
                                    "Band":["0"]}
                                }] ;
```

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: First, what's the reason you want to do that?

Comment: This is not something angular can help you with. This is pure JavaScript coding problem. You can use underscore.js or lodash.js and use it's map function to transform you json object to another form.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kachhalimbu that you can use underscore.js or lodash.js and use it's map function to transform you json object to another form.

If you still want to transform without using another framework you can do something like this:

```
var filterObject = { "filters": {} };

angular.forEach($scope.filters.filters, function(filter) {
  if(!filterObject.filters[filter.filtername]) {
    filterObject.filters[filter.filtername] = [];
  }
  filterObject.filters[filter.filtername].push(filter.filterValue)
});
```

filterObject will contains that format you want to use, after that you can do something like this:

```
$scope.filters = [];
$scope.filters.push(filterObject);
```